# how do i access "class" attribute value of a <td> element in codebehind vb.net 

Tags: vb.net

I also want to store it in a string to check a condition . And again set it wilth a new value if a condition is met.
string s = HtmlCell.Attributes["class"]
not working
I have added runat="server" and added an id for it as well. But i guess HtmlCell.Attributes["class"] is cant be cast into a String. I want to access the value of  'class' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your TD is either a `<asp:tableCell>` or a `<td id="sometd" runat="server">`, than you can access/change the sometd.cssClass